# Firebase, doing (somewhat) heavy computation, cloud function VS client side

Tags: firebase, function, cloud

Suppose I have the following flow:

1. A client updates a document (docA) in Firestore
2. (Somewhat) heavy computation is required, and the result of this computation is saved in another document/s (docA, docB)

It feels more "natural" to use Cloud Functions for that (triggered when docA is updated), but for a system that serves a lot of clients - I'm not sure if there's a **performance penalty** here.
So maybe it's better to do the computation on the client side and update the relevant documents by the client...

I'd love if someone can shed a light on this issue :)

p.s.
No need for immediate update, so no problem with function's latency